# How to wait for results from multiple async methods wrapped in a for loop?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, asynchronous

I'm developing a search algorithm which searches through 3 databases and prints out the results. The general structure of the code looks something like this:

```js
for(type in ["player", "team", "event"]){
   this.searchService.getSearchResult(type).toPromise()
   .then(search_result => {
      if(type == "player"){
        this.player_search_results_full = this.getPlayerSearchResults(search_result, search_string);
      }
      if(type == "team"){
        this.team_search_results_full = this.getTeamSearchResults(search_result, search_string);
      }
      if(type == "event"){
        this.event_search_results_full = this.getEventSearchResults(search_result, search_string);
      }
   })
}
// this.getFinalDisplayResults()

getFinalDisplayResults(){
  // Do some actions on <type>_search_results_full lists
}
```

Those `<type>_search_results_full` will be a list that contains the full list of matches for the search_string. I'd like to then wait for all of those lists to be populated, then run them through another method `getFinalDisplayResults` which chooses a total of X number of results to display from those full lists.

The issue I'm facing is that `this.getFinalDisplayResults()` executes before those `<type>_search_results_full` lists are full. I tried putting everything in the for loop in a separate method `getFullResults()` and then doing something like this:

```js
async getFinalDisplayResults(){
  await getFullResults()
  // Do something
}
```

But that seems to not work, as adding some logs shows that the for-loop in getFullResults() finishes without the lists being populated.

I don't have a strong understanding of toPromise() and asynchronous methods, so I'm sure I'm just approaching this incorrectly. Can someone help me understand what I should be doing instead?

Comment: I'm slightly confused what you're asking but I think `Promise.all` is what you're looking for.

Comment: @bmorgs note that [Promise.allSettled()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/allSettled) is sometimes more appropriate than Promise.all(), particularly if there is a chance the async calls might fail, and you wish to take action on a partial success...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think I know what you try to achieve, and the issue you are having, `this.getFinalDisplayResults()` is executed before you have the results because the logic inside the for loop is asynchronous, so the fix would be.

```js
async function getDataFromBackend () {
    for(let type in ["player", "team", "event"]) {
        const searchResult = await this.searchService.getSearchResult(type).toPromise()
        if(type === "player")
            this.player_search_results_full = this.getPlayerSearchResults(searchResult, search_string);
           
        if(type === "team")
             this.team_search_results_full = this.getTeamSearchResults(searchResult, search_string);
           
        if(type === "event")
             this.event_search_results_full = this.getEventSearchResults(searchResult, search_string);  
     }
}

  

async function getFinalDisplayResults() {
            await getDataFromBackend(); // this will ensure you have the data, before you do the rest of the process
    //rest of the logic here
}
```

Comment: `getDataFromBackend` uses its `this` value. The easiest way to support this  may be to call it using `await this.getDataFromBackend()` with the proviso that `getDataFromBackend` should be a sibling method of the `getFinalDisplayResults` method posted.

Comment: Beautiful, this is exactly what I was trying to achieve. I'm relatively new to angular and services, so I didn't know I the syntax  "const searchResult = await this.searchService.getSearchResult(type).toPromise()" was possible. That really helps, thank you!

Comment: Good to know that I was able to help, first time doing it by the way

Answer (score 2):

I tkink what you are looking for is `Promise.all`, as it takes an array of Promise and resolves to an array of results.

With your example, it could be something like :

```js
const results = await Promise.all(["player", "team", "event"].map( type => 
   this.searchService.getSearchResult(type).toPromise()
))
```

Answer (score 0):

We can clean it up a little, mainly by iterating the things that vary over the array of types.

```
const promises = [
  { type: 'player', method: 'getPlayerSearchResults'},
  { type: 'team', method: 'getTeamSearchResults'},
  { type: 'event', method: 'getEventSearchResults'}
].map(obj => {
  return this.searchService.getSearchResult(obj.type).toPromise().then(search_result => {
    return this[obj.method].bind(this)(search_result, search_string);
  })
});
return Promise.all(promises);
```